# grep -v no longer excluding pattern after migration

Tags: grep, cron, find, redhat

One of our shared hosting sites got moved recently.  New server is Red Hat 4.8.5-36. The other binaries' versions are grep (GNU grep) 2.20  and find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11

This cron job had previously functioned fine for at least 6 years and gave us a list of updated files which did not match logs, cache etc.

```
find /home/example/example.com/public_html/ -mmin -12 \
    | grep -v 'error_log|logs|cache'
```

After the move the `-v` seems to be ineffectual and we get results like

```
/home/example/example.com/public_html/products/cache/ssu/pc/d/5/c
```

The change in results occurred immediately after the move.  Anyone have an idea why it is now broken?  Additionally - how do I restore the filtered output?

Comment: `grep -v 'error_log|logs|cache'` looks for the exact string `error_log|logs|cache` – alternation is ignored. Are you sure you didn't use `grep -Ev` or `egrep -v`?

Comment: Also, you don't need `grep` here at all – you could use three `-name` statements, or one `-regex` statement instead.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I can't be sure.  It was ages ago.  I just know we were not getting notices of the log and cache updates but we were getting informed of other new and modified files all during that time.  The admins ported our crontab and the cron job looked like I remembered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to exclude a group of words.

```
grep -v -e 'error_log' -e 'logs' -e 'cache' file
```

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '!/error_log|logs|cache/' file
```

It will exclude all lines with these words.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v 'error_log|logs|cache'
```

only excludes strings that contain literally `error_log|logs|cache`. To use alternation, use extended regular expressions:

```
grep -Ev 'error_log|logs|cache'
```

GNU grep supports alternation as an extension to Basic Regular Expressions, but `|` needs to be escaped, so this might work as well:

```
grep -v 'error_log\|logs\|cache'
```

However, grep isn't required in the first place, we can use (GNU) `find` to do all the work:

```
find /home/example/example.com/public_html/ -mmin -12 \
    -not \( -name '*error_log*' -or -name '*logs*' -or -name '*cache*' \)
```

or, POSIX compliant:

```
find /home/example/example.com/public_html/ -mmin -12 \
    \! \( -name '*error_log*' -o -name '*logs*' -o -name '*cache*' \)
```

or, if your `find` supports `-regex` (both GNU and BSD `find` do):

```
find /home/example/example.com/public_html/ -mmin -12 \
    -not -regex '.*\(error_log\|logs\|cache\).*'
```